# Avoiding repetition when using the in operator in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

Consider this Typescript code:

```
type A = {
    foo: string
    bar: string
}

type B = {
    baz: string
}

type U = A | B;

function f(obj: U) {
    if ('foo' in obj && obj.foo) {
        console.log(obj.foo, obj.bar);
    }
}
```

For Typescript to infer that `obj` is of type `B`, the `'foo' in obj` check is needed, but logically, it is redundant, since the truthy check of `obj.foo` implies that it exists.

This leads to a repetition though. foo has to be referenced twice in the if condition, which I'd like to get rid of.

I attempted to write a type predicate for this, something like:

```
function isTruthyProp<T extends Object>(obj: T, prop): obj is T & {[prop]: unknown} {
    return prop in obj && !!obj[prop];
}
```

But not only does it not work (error: A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.), it also probably wouldn't even matter if it did, because it's (a) not going to infer a better type than 'unknown', and (b) it cannot infer that `foo.bar` is valid inside the if-clause, like the in operator can.

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, i.e., avoiding having to type `foo` twice?

Comment: Do you really need the `obj.foo` check? I think we can get going with just `'foo' in obj` check in the `if` condition. https://tsplay.dev/WJVj6W

Comment: Well, in my case console.log() is not actually console.log() but a function that requires a non-empty string.

Comment: If you want to just check `obj.foo` then your `U` type needs to look more like `{foo: string, bar: string, baz?: never} | {foo?: never, bar?: never, baz: string}` so that the compiler understands that it's always safe to index into `obj` with `foo` and that the result can narrow the type, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wezK1N).  Does that meet your needs? If so I could write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz: Thanks for the suggestion. I think the linked question/answer (which you wrote!) was already helpful. If my types have to be shaped the way you suggest, then I think I'll just have to live with having the `'prop' in obj` check.